# Fill input with max value on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to find a way to fill the max value of an input according to the

```
max="@value"
```

Currently I'm using asp.net mvc, I'm getting data from a datatable and I render this information inside a html table where in my tr> /tr> I have a td> /td> that looks like this

```
 <td align="center"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" min="0" max="@monto.Trim()" value="" step="any" style="width: 100px" /></td>1
```

Can anyone tell me how to make a javascript function that automatically fills the max="" value inside a Html TableRow?

The problem is that each row has its unique max @value

Comment: In what context? If you have an element reference then you can get the attribute value by `element.max` if it's in an event handler then you could probably use `event.currentTarget.max` and so on

Comment: Replace `oninput="setValueAttr(this)"` with `onclick="this.value=max"`.

Comment: I'm currently using ```oninput="setValueAttr(this)"``` on another script where I push into an array the rows that do have a value in the input in order to post it with AJAX
```function setValueAttr(el) {el.setAttribute('value', el.value)}```

Comment: @apokryfos can you give me an example with an event handler? I'm currently looking for a way to do it this way, will adding a button on the same ```<td>``` catch the event handler?

Comment: Well I do not know what the idea behind you code actually is, but `onclick` is not the same as `oninput`. So if you want to react on click, like the title suggests, use `onclick`.

Comment: @Lain o wow that was blind IceeFrog, let me work on that :D thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following HTML:

```html
<td align="center">
     <input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" min="0" max="@monto.Trim()" value="" step="any" style="width: 100px" />
     <button class="set-max">Max value</button>
</td>
```

You can add an event listener on the button via JavaScript e.g. put this code in the bottom of your table or in the bottom of the `<body>` tag.

```js
<script>
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.set-max'); 
buttons.forEach(function (button) {
   button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       var input = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
       input.value = input.max;
   });
};
<script>
```

If the button ends up somewhere else you'd need to adjust the event listener to find the actual target element by navigating through the DOM hierarchy

Comment: Yay thanks for the explanation, totally helped me out thanks sir!